# Parsing JSON list object to Ruby hash

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, list, hash

So I want to parse this JSON to a Ruby hash but the JSON has a `list` type so I don't know how to work with this. Anyone can help me? How can I parse it to Ruby? Thanks

```
 [
    {
        "name": "unknown script",
        "groups": [
            {
                "name": "unknown group",
                "labels": {},
                "headers": {
                    "sorted": [],
                    "map": {}
                },
                "agent": "",
                "group_type": "",
                "top_comments": [],
                "bottom_comments": [],
                "checks": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "value": "0",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "one",
                        "value": "0",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "two",

                        "value": "1",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "three",

                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "four",

                        "value": "0",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "five",

                        "value": "0",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "six",

                        "value": "0",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "seven",

                        "value": "1",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "eight",

                        "value": "1",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "nine",

                        "value": "0",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "ten",
                        "value": "0",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "eleven",
                        "value": "1",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "twelve",
                        "value": "1",
                        "type": "compare"
                    },
  
                 
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: This is not a complete or repeatable example. Please update your code with a minimal *valid* example of your input, and a sample (even if it's hand-crafted) of your expected output. NB: See `JSON.parse`.

Comment: This is still invalid input. Per jq: `parse error: Expected another array element at line 91, column 33`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JSON Array of Objects becomes a Ruby [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) of [Hashes](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html). These Hashes can then contain more Arrays and so on.

If you want to access the Hashes, you need to iterate through the Array. If you want to access the groups you need to iterate again.

```
scripts = JSON.parse(json)

# Iterate through each script
scripts.each { |script|
  # Print the script's name.
  puts "Script: #{script["name"]}"

  # Iterate through the script's groups.
  groups = script["groups"]
  groups.each { |group|
    # Print each group's name.
    puts "Group: #{group["name"]}"
  }
}
```